# Powershell output logging when using a text file to gather server names

Tags: powershell

Have a bit of an issue whereby would like to figure out the best way to handle success or failures. Have a powershell query which checks the dcom port range, if it is within the specified value output to a success file, if not a failure file. The issue is, it seems to be outputting the entire serverlist.txt for a success and need to know a way to break this down so it only appends a server (either success/failure) to it, not all at once.

Here is the powershell script contents:

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass .\DCOMPortRange.ps1
```

Where DCOMPortRange.ps1 contains

```
$computername = Get-Content -Path "C:\Folderpath\serverlist.txt"
$val = (Get-ItemProperty "hklm:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc\Internet") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Ports

if($val -eq "50000-50500")
{
    Write-Output "$computername" | out-file C:\folderpath\Success.log -append
} Else {
    Write-Output "$computername" | out-file C:\folderpath\Failure.log -append
}
```

The issue is the error path lets say is a success it appends the entire server list.

Please advise?

Comment: Can I suggest both for your own testing, and the questions - reducing this down to the condition check. Does the "val eq" part of your code do what you are expecting it to?

Comment: Your code will output the entire list of computers in `serverlist.txt`, since that is what you are trying to output. I suggest using a [foreach](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/28/basics-of-powershell-looping-foreach/) loop and try it out once.

Comment: The actual output is great and is correctly flags if the range is within 50000-50500 which leads to an entry in success. If its not in the range this also works and outputs to failure. Its just from my perspective to then audit the logs, it is confusing as it is polling all the entire serverlist.txt (which has the servers I need to check) Just need better logging so it outputs a server induvidually (whether it is success/failure)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. This does require that you do have PSremoting enabled on the servers

```
$computername = Get-Content -Path "C:\Folderpath\serverlist.txt"

ForEach ($server in $computername) {

$val = Invoke-Command -Computername $server -ScriptBlock {(Get-ItemProperty "hklm:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc\Internet") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Ports}

if ($val -ge 50000 -and $val -le 50500) {
    Write-Output "$server" | out-file C:\folderpath\Success.log -append
}
Else {
    Write-Output "$server" | out-file C:\folderpath\Failure.log -append
}
}
```

Edit: A change to the if statement

/Anders

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the functionality works..but I am still at the situation of it appending the full server list to the output. Lets say I put in 1 legitimate servers and 2 dummy (not contactable servers) in serverlist.txt. If the dcom range is 50000-50500 it creates a success.log BUT it also appends to the 2 dummy servers to it. In theory the 2 dummy servers belong in the Failure.log :(

Comment: Are you sure? Here at me its working like intended. Maybe its old entrys in the log files?

Comment: Im unable to get the logging aspect to work at all, for example if I have the serverlist.txt with a server named 'dummy' will appear as if it is querying the server I am running the powershell script on (which is within the dcom range) but output the servername regardless..so its as if it hasnt even tried to query dummy as that server does not even exist..so should simply error out?

Comment: Just to add got this working, but without the serverlist, had to use: $remotecomputername = @("PC1","PC2","RealServerName") this then queried each server and errored on the dummy servers that it could not connect to remote server.

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad. I forgot the -computer name paramter. I will edit my post. How was your text fil formatted?

Comment: No probs, It was seperated with a comma (Server1, Server2, Server3) it has worked before for previous scripts. Still stumped why the text file was not being looped through :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$remotecomputername = @("PC1","PC2","RealServerName")
ForEach ($computer in $remotecomputername) {
Invoke-Command -Computername $computer -ScriptBlock { $val = (Get-
ItemProperty "hklm:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc\Internet") | Select-Object -
ExpandProperty Ports} }
if($val -eq "50000-50500") {
write-host $computer DCOM Port in Range
} else {
write-host $computer DCOM Port not in range
}
```